# How can we consume JSON data using OPENUI5/SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5/OPENUI5.
I am trying out a sample program to consume json data from a domain and display it in my openui5 table. I have tried two methods to get the data and bind it to table control.But I am not able to generate the table with the json data. 
Please let me know my mistake in the code.
And also please refer me some links to understand the concept in a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Please find the two approaches below :

JSON Data :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rajesh"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kunal Jauhari"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ashish Singh"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ansuman Parhi"
  },
  {
    "name": "Arup Kumar"
  },
  {
    "name": "Deepak Malviya"
  },
  {
    "name": "Seshu"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ankush Datey"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tapesh Syawaria"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mahesh"
  },
  {
    "name": "Vinay Joshi"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ardhendu Karna"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abhishek Shukla"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kashim"
  },
  {
    "name": "Vinayak"
  }
]
```

Approach 1 : I am using a php file to echo the JSON data and use it in my ui5 screen.
When I access the run the php file individually, it generates the data and prints the data on screen.

Error I get is getJSON is not called.

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>


        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>
        <!-- add sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3 and/or other libraries to 'data-sap-ui-libs' if required -->

        <script>
        var json_url = "http://mydomain/teamdetails_ui5.php?t=6";
            $.ajax({
                url : json_url,
                jsonpCallback : 'getJSON',  
                contentType : "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',


                success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                    oModel.setData({data: data});
                    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

                    var oTable1 = new sap.ui.table.Table({  
                        title : "Players List",  
                        visibleRowCount : 3,  
                        selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,  
                        navigationMode : sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator,  
                    });

                    //Define the columns and the control templates to be used    
                    oTable1.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({  
                        label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({  
                        text : "Player Name"  
                    }),  
                    template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty(  
                    "text", "name"),  
                    width : "10px"  
                    }));

                    oTable1.setModel(oModel);  
                    oTable1.bindRows("/oModel");  
                    oTable1.placeAt('table_cont');  

                },
                error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                    alert("Oh no, an error occurred");
                    alert(jqXHR);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);             
                }
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="table_cont"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Approach 2 : I am trying to access the JSON file directly on my domain and access the data.

Code is the same as above except url.
Url is used for this approach is (mydomain/players.json) where players.json contain the above json data.

Please help me in understanding the concept of JSON data handling.

Regards,
Rajan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: SAPUI5 is built onto jQuery, yes. But there should be no need to use jQuery inside your SAPUI5 Application.

Use a **JSONModel** to load JSON-Data. Also the JSONModel can load the data from URL.
See the **[Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData)**

this will look like:

```
// create a "json" Model
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
// load data from URL
oModel.loadData('http://mydomain/teamdetails_ui5.php?t=6');
```

after this you can register this model in your sap.ui.core with:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
```

after this line every control can use the data from this model by simple binding-syntax.

Now lets create the table:

```
// create your table
var oTable1 = new sap.ui.table.Table({  
   title : "Players List",  
   visibleRowCount : 3,  
   selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,  
   navigationMode : sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator,
   // bind the core-model to this table by aggregating player-Array
   rows: '{/player}'
});
```

beware of the part with "**rows: '{/player}'**". This is the only thing that has to be done to get the data from the model inside your table.

now finish the demo by adding the column and add the table to the DOM:

```
// define the columns and the control templates to be used    
oTable1.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({  
   label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({  
      text : "Player Name"  
   }),  
   template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
      text: '{name}'
   }),
   width : "10px"  
}));

//place at DOM
oTable1.placeAt('content');
```

Thats it. If it doesn't work, here is a running **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/openui5-js-view/256/)**.

Comment: Hi Manuel,
Thanks for your time and reply.
I tried and executed the your demo version.
It is working. When I try loading the data from URL, I am getting the below error in my console.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain/teamdetails_ui5.php?t=6. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Please let me know why do i get this error.

Regards,
Rajan

Comment: To perform AJAX-request you need to have `teamdetails_ui5.php` and `index.html` of your application on same domain. It's a browsers' restriction. Other way you could pass HTTP header 'Origin: *' from server where `index.html` is.

Comment: As comment above already said. This is a browser restriction. You cannot load data from another domain as your own. You can use JSONP to get data from another domain. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132007/sapui5-jsonmodel-and-jsonp

Comment: Thanks a lot Nikolay and Manuel. I am able to fetch the data after placing the index.html in the same domain as teamdetails_ui5.php. Thanks a lot to both of you once again.